# How to port Tomcat 6 application from Windows XP to Linux?

Tags: linux, hibernate, tomcat6, jbpm, migrate

I have a Tomcat 6 application running in 32 bit Windows XP, which uses Hibernate, Spring, JBOss jBPM 3.2.

I need to port this application to Linux Centos 64 bit. In Linux i downloaded and setup JDK 1.6. I then downloaded apache-tomcat-6.0.37.tar.gz and unzipped it. I start the Tomcat.

I imagine i have to do the following steps :-

- replicate server.xml settings from XP to Linux
- copy Common/lib jar files from XP to Linux (i guess this is where Hibernate, Spring, jBPM, JBoss references jars will be available)
- Copy the contents of webapps folder from XP to Linux. (What about the  differences between the 2 systems ? )

Am i right in what i plan above ? Any mistakes there ?

Can you point out any further steps to run the application in Linux ?

Comment: Just copy the webapps folder fully to the new tomcat.

Comment: @Maximin In many cases, just moving the webapp will cause problems. Any slightly complex tomcat installations will have path separators somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't think `Tomcat 6` had a common/lib? Are you moving from a Tomcat 5.5 to 6? 
Be careful copying libs from `lib` or `common/lib` as they might be version / arch / OS dependant. Just copy your own jars and dependencies.

I would also, extract your information from the old `server.xml` and input that into the new one. Again, there maybe slight differences especially if there are version differences.

Make sure that if there are any context files in `conf/Calalina/localhost` that you copy those as well and check if they have absolute paths - if so they will need changing.

The main issues I have when moving tomcat applications from Windows to Unix is paths and path separators. Hopefully you've no hard coded path separators in the code, but you may have config files - especially logging configs that define paths.

Check for `logging.properties` or `log4j.xml` or similar files - they will define paths.

Hope this helps,

Will

Comment: When i try to download activemq-all-5.1.0.jar , i get one link for windows zip file and another link for Linux tar.gz file. Is this segregation just because windows uses winzip and Linux uses tar ? Or is it because the 2 JAR files are fundamentally different for the different OS ?

Comment: @Chakra Not sure, best ask a new question.